# ag-grid react) Is there an event when I lose focus?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

The event should simply be called when the focus is lost.
not `onCellEditingStopped`.
I use '[CellRenderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/)', and this is because you can edit the contents of the cell and determine that the editing is over when the cell loses focus.